# Problem when download Python package and then install from .whl files

Tags: python, django, pip

I want to download Python package `pipy.org` and move them to another machine and finally install that packages with downloaded `.whl` files in that machine
This is `requirements.txt` file:

```
amqp==5.1.1
anytree==2.8.0
asgiref==3.5.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==22.1.0
autobahn==22.7.1
Automat==22.10.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==5.2.7
certifi==2022.9.24
cffi==1.15.1
channels==4.0.0
channels-redis==4.0.0
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
constantly==15.1.0
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
cryptography==38.0.3
daphne==4.0.0
Deprecated==1.2.13
Django==4.0.8
django-celery-beat==2.3.0
django-celery-results==2.4.0
django-filter==22.1
django-jalali==6.0.0
django-timezone-field==5.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.2
drf-yasg==1.21.4
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
h2==4.1.0
hpack==4.0.0
hyperframe==6.0.1
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.4
incremental==22.10.0
inflection==0.5.1
itypes==1.2.0
jdatetime==4.1.0
Jinja2==3.1.2
kombu==5.2.4
lxml==4.9.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
msgpack==1.0.4
multitasking==0.0.11
numpy==1.23.3
openpyxl==3.0.10
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.5.0
pandas-datareader==0.10.0
Pillow==9.2.0
priority==1.3.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.31
psutil==5.9.2
psycopg2==2.9.4
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.6.0
pyOpenSSL==22.1.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-crontab==2.6.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.21.0
pytz==2022.4
redis==4.3.4
requests==2.28.1
ruamel.yaml==0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.7
service-identity==21.1.0
simplejson==3.17.6
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
sqlparse==0.4.3
Twisted==22.10.0
txaio==22.2.1
typing_extensions==4.4.0
tzdata==2022.5
Unidecode==1.3.6
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.12
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
wrapt==1.14.1
yfinance==0.1.74
zope.interface==5.5.1
```

I did download packages with:

```
pip download -r requirements.txt
```

This is list of downloaded pacakges in `~/LocalPythonPackage` directory:

```
→ ls 
amqp-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl                                             lxml-4.9.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl
anytree-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                      MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl                                          msgpack-1.0.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
async_timeout-4.0.2-py3-none-any.whl                                    multitasking-0.0.11-py3-none-any.whl
attrs-22.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                       numpy-1.23.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
autobahn-22.7.1.tar.gz                                                  openpyxl-3.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Automat-22.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                    packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl
beautifulsoup4-4.11.1-py3-none-any.whl                                  pandas-1.5.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
billiard-3.6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl                                       pandas_datareader-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl
celery-5.2.7-py3-none-any.whl                                           Pillow-9.2.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl
certifi-2022.9.24-py3-none-any.whl                                      priority-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
cffi-1.15.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl  prompt_toolkit-3.0.31-py3-none-any.whl
channels-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl                                         psutil-5.9.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
channels_redis-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl                                   psycopg2-2.9.4.tar.gz
charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl                               pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl                                            pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
click_didyoumean-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl                                 pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
click_plugins-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                PyJWT-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
click_repl-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl                                       pyOpenSSL-22.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                  pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl
coreapi-2.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                      python-crontab-2.6.0.tar.gz
coreschema-0.0.4.tar.gz                                                 python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
cryptography-38.0.3-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl                 python_dotenv-0.21.0-py3-none-any.whl
daphne-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl                                           pytz-2022.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Deprecated-1.2.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                  redis-4.3.4-py3-none-any.whl
Django-4.0.8-py3-none-any.whl                                           requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
django_celery_beat-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl                               ruamel.yaml-0.17.21-py3-none-any.whl
django_celery_results-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl                            ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.7-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl
django_filter-22.1-py3-none-any.whl                                     service_identity-21.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
django_jalali-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl                                    setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl
djangorestframework-3.14.0-py3-none-any.whl                             simplejson-3.17.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
djangorestframework_simplejwt-5.2.2-py3-none-any.whl                    six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
django_timezone_field-5.0-py3-none-any.whl                              soupsieve-2.3.2.post1-py3-none-any.whl
drf_yasg-1.21.4-py3-none-any.whl                                        sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl
et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl                                       Twisted-22.10.0-py3-none-any.whl
gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl                                        txaio-22.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
h2-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl                                               typing_extensions-4.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
hpack-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl                                            tzdata-2022.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
hyperframe-6.0.1-py3-none-any.whl                                       Unidecode-1.3.6-py3-none-any.whl
hyperlink-21.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                   uritemplate-4.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl                                               urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
incremental-22.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                vine-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
inflection-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                   wcwidth-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
itypes-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl                                       wrapt-1.14.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
jdatetime-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl                                        yfinance-0.1.74-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl                                           zope.interface-5.5.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
```

and after copy all `.whl files to traget computer, I did run this code:

```
pip install --no-index --find-links ~/LocalPythonPackage -r requirements.txt
```

But I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MarkupSafe==2.1.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MarkupSafe==2.1.1
```

I use `python3.11` and `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS` in both computers. I think that, this problem is for dependencies or different in `OS`.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can we see the text output of `ls -l ~/LocalPythonPackage` ?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I will edit my question. @phd

Comment: Change it to jinja2==3.0.0 then try installing again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You need to use `--platform` and `--only-binary=:all:` (sometimes need to specify `--abi` and `--python-version` as well) flags to download wheels that is compatible with your installation target machine.

```bash
pip3 download --only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux2014_aarch64 -r requirements.txt
```

(Important: if your target machine is not `aarch64` architecture, replace the `manylinux2014_aarch64` with the correct platform tag)

---

### Some wheels are platform dependent

**The error happens because pip can't install the MarkupSafe wheel you provided in the directory, therefore it says it can't find a valid distribution.**

Since you mentioned the two computers are same in Python version and OS distribution, I'm gonna guess that the two computers you use are different in architectures. (ex. the target computer is aarch64)

The following explanation and solution are based on this guess.

The [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#wheels) states a Python wheel could be either a "pure Python wheel" or a "platform wheel". When a Python package contains extensions that requires compilation, the produced wheel will be platform-specific and cannot be installed on other non-compatible platforms.

In your case, the wheel `MarkupSafe-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl` is a platform wheel built for  Python 3.10 runtime, [manylinux2014](https://peps.python.org/pep-0599/) and x86_64 architecture machines.

The wheel filename is defined in [PEP 491](https://peps.python.org/pep-0491/#:%7E:text=The%20wheel%20filename%20is%20%7Bdistribution,whl%20.&text=Distribution%20name%2C%20e.g.%20%27django%27%2C%20%27pyramid%27.&text=Distribution%20version%2C%20e.g.%201.0.), formatted as `{distribution}-{version}(-{build tag})?-{python tag}-{abi tag}-{platform tag}.whl`.

> The last three components of the filename before the extension are called “compatibility tags.” The compatibility tags express the package’s basic interpreter requirements and are detailed in PEP 425.

Hence by the name of a wheel (to be precise, the last three component in the filename) you can find out if it is a pure Python wheel or a platform wheel.

### Newer Python versions (except different major versions) can still install platform wheels built for older minor versions

Another answer in the post says you need to install a wheel that has the same miner Python version in the Python tag, but that is usually not true.

According to [PEP 425](https://peps.python.org/pep-0425/#id1):

> The tags are used by installers to decide which built distribution (if any) to download from a list of potential built distributions. The installer maintains a list of (pyver, abi, arch) tuples that it will support. If the built distribution’s tag is in the list, then it can be installed.

That means `pip` is responsible for make decision whether a distribution could be installed on the current system.

Let's take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/main/src/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py#L385) of `pip`. The `CandidateEvaluator` evaluate possible distribution candidates when trying to install a package.

If you trace the code all the way to `_py_interpreter_range`, you'll find out a list of older Python minor versions are appended to the supported tags in descending order.

For Python 3.11, `Python 3.10`, `Python 3.9`, `Python 3.8`... are all considered supported tags for pip.

### Solution

> pip download with the `--platform`, `--python-version`, `--implementation`, and `--abi` options provides the ability to fetch dependencies for an interpreter and system other than the ones that pip is running on. `--only-binary=:all:` or `--no-deps` is required when using any of these options.

from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/.

To download `MarkupSafe` for `manylinux2014_aarch64`:

```bash
$ pip3 download --only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux2014_aarch64 MarkupSafe
```

And change your package preparation command to:

```bash
pip3 download --only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux2014_aarch64 -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: How to find out `abi` on traget machine? @james-chien

Comment: I could find platform with `setuptools.distutils.util.get_platform()` that print `linux-x86_64`. But there is no `many` keyword on that. Is it correct?

Comment: I run this line: `pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform linux-x86_64 --implementation cp --python-version 3.11  -r requirements.txt` but I got `ERROR: No matching distribution found for autobahn==22.7.1`

Comment: See https://pypi.org/simple/autobahn/, for the version you specified (22.7.1), only the source package (`autobahn-22.7.1.tar.gz`) is published to official PyPI. So when you enable the `--only-binary=:all:` flag, pip would not be able to find a matching distribution since the only valid distribution is not binary.

Comment: To download and install it, you could run `pip3 download --no-deps --platform linux-x86_64 --python-version 3.11 autobahn==22.7.1` to download the `autobahn-22.7.1.tar.gz`, and install it on the other machine just like how you install regular wheels using the `pip install` command.

Comment: If you want all dependencies downloaded as well so that your second machine doesn't have to fetch any package via internet, you'll need to manually download all the dependencies if you use `--no-deps` flag. Yeah I know it's very troublesome, but as far as I know there's no any convenient tool to prepare installation packages for a different platform in a simple command. You'll have to deal with possible issues for each package, such as this package that only source package is released and no wheel is available.

Answer (score 0):

You use Python 3.11 but wheels you show above are for Python 3.10. You should download packages on a host with the same processor architecture (x64 seems to be your case), the same OS and version (Ubuntu 20) and the same minor Python version (Python 3.11.*, that is any Python 3.11 does but not Python 3.10) as the target host.

Or use Python 3.10 on the offline host.